# ObjectForKey is returning nil sometimes

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to set an object to a dictionary with key as an object. The test cases works fine, but within the actual code, I am not able to get the value for the key. The `NSMutableDictionary` has the key value in it, but when debugging it returns `nil`.

```
@implementation JSHashMap {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict;
}

- (instancetype)initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)array {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        dict = [self fromArray:array];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)fromArray:(NSMutableArray *)array {
    NSMutableDictionary* _dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    NSUInteger i = 0, len = [array count];
    if (len % 2 != 0) {
        error(@"JSError: Odd number of elements in the array.");
        return _dict;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < len; i = i + 2) {
        [_dict setObject:array[i + 1] forKey:array[i]];
        assert([_dict objectForKey:array[i]] != nil);
    }
    debug(@"%@", _dict);
    return _dict;
}

- (JSData *)objectForKey:(id)key {
    return [dict objectForKey:key];
}
```

I am creating the hash map using the `initWithArray` method.

```
(lldb) po [dict objectForKey:key]
 nil
```

The `key` passed in and the key in the dictionary has the same memory address `0x100ea2fa0`.

[image: screenshot - debug variables]

The test cases works fine though. But the when running the actual program, it fails.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
JSNumber *val = [[JSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1];
JSNumber *key = [[JSNumber alloc] initWithInt:2];
[dict setObject:val forKey:key];
JSData * ret = [dict objectForKey:key];
XCTAssertNotNil(ret);
XCTAssertEqualObjects([ret dataType], @"JSNumber");
JSHashMap *hm = [[JSHashMap alloc] initWithArray:[@[key, val] mutableCopy]];
JSData * ret1 = [hm objectForKey:key];
XCTAssertNotNil(ret1);
XCTAssertEqualObjects([ret1 dataType], @"JSNumber");
```

```
JSHashMap *dict = (JSHashMap *)ast;
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
NSUInteger i = 0;
NSUInteger len = [keys count];
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    id key = keys[i];
    JSData *val = (JSData *)[dict objectForKey:key];
    // Issue -> val is getting nil 
}
```

How to fix this and why is this random behaviour?

---

Found the failing test case.

```
NSArray *keys = [hm allKeys];
XCTAssertTrue([keys count] == 1);
JSData *ret = [hm objectForKey:keys[0]];
XCTAssertNotNil(ret);
```

If I use the key returned from calling `allKeys` method, it returns nil.

Comment: You are going to confuse yourself and everyone else. Properties - no underscore. Instance variables - underscore. Local variables - no underscore. Always. No exception.

Comment: And it looks like you copied some code that is at least five years old. And why on earth are you initialising with a mutable array?

Comment: Right, the array does not have to be mutable. I did not copy any code. I wrote it on my own :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not shown any information about what JSNumber is, but I am betting that it does not implement `isEqual` and `hash` correctly. Thus, you cannot successfully use it as a key in an NSDictionary.

Comment: I have `isEqual` implemented, but I don't have `hash` implemented.

Comment: Well there you go. Subscripting lookup on a dictionary can't work if its keys are of a type that does not implement `hash` correctly.

Comment: And why are you implementing a class named JSNumber? Use JSValue, or use NSNumber, or you get yourself into trouble as you've seen.

Comment: I am implementing another language (interpreter) in Objective-C. These are the data type classes that works with the language's AST.

Comment: Also make sure the class conforms to `<NSCopying>` protocol (keys are copied).

Comment: @NSGod Very good addition. However, my memory (vague to be sure) is that if you don't do that, you'll get notified at runtime — whereas you can fail to implement `isEqual` or `hash` and just go blithely on, as there is no runtime check (because, I suppose, the implementation from NSObject is just inherited).